# How to order matrix based on elements of 2 different matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices. The one (per) is a permutation and the other matrix (wh) based on each element of the per matrix contains some calculations.

```
    > per=permutations(3,3,c(1,2,3))
    > per
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    2    3
    [2,]    1    3    2
    [3,]    2    1    3
    [4,]    2    3    1
    [5,]    3    1    2
    [6,]    3    2    1

> wh
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "w1" "w2" "w3"
[2,] "w1" "w3" "w2"
[3,] "w2" "w1" "w3"
[4,] "w2" "w3" "w1"
[5,] "w3" "w1" "w2"
[6,] "w3" "w2" "w1"
```

What I want to do, is to create a new matrix (whr) that will  order matrix wh in the form w1,w2,w3

What I am doing now, is that I try to fill the matrix with a for loop. For a row i, I detect where the element in matrix per lies (e.g. 4) and given this position, I detect where it lies the respective w4 and then I fill the matrix whr accordingly.

I am doing this with the loop

```
for (i in 1:720){
    whr[i,per[i,1]]=wh[i,1]
    whr[i,per[i,2]]=wh[i,2]
    whr[i,per[i,3]]=wh[i,3]
    whr[i,per[i,4]]=wh[i,4]
    whr[i,per[i,5]]=wh[i,5]
    whr[i,per[i,6]]=wh[i,6]
```

It does the job but it is painfully slow. I try to vectorize it but I am not sure how.

I give the general command

```
whr[,per[,1]]=wh[,1]
```

to do the same for all elements 1 and accordingly for 2-6 but it does not work. 
Any suggestions  are more that welcome.

Comment: Are you referring to matrix wh as hr? And then you have saved matrix wh as l?

Comment: Apologies for this mistake and many thanks for noticing. The text is now edited.

Comment: Could you post the wanted "whr" output based on "per" and "wh"? You mention _column_ `i` but you use `i` as row indexing in your loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct, but the following looks valid, doesn't it? `matrix(t(wh)[order(t(per + (seq_len(nrow(per)) - 1) * ncol(per)))], nrow(wh), ncol(wh), byrow = T)`

Comment: Many thanks for your response. It does the job exactly as I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have left some gaps for us to try to reproduce your code (no package mentioned as well as mixing up 3 or 6) but let's suppose you want something like

```
library(gtools)
n   = 3
per = permutations(n, n, 1:n)
wh  = permutations(n, n, paste0("wh", 1:n))
whr = matrix(NA, nrow=factorial(n), ncol=n)
for (i in 1:factorial(n)){ for (j in 1:n){ whr[i,per[i,j]] = wh[i,j] } }
```

If you do not want the double loop in the final line then replacing it with the following would reduce to a single loop and produce the same result

```
for (i in 1:factorial(n)){ whr[i,] <- wh[i, order(per[i,])] }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. It does what I want to do but still the loop for is there. Isn't there any way to get rid of the for so that the code will speed up a bit?

Comment: It rather depends on what you actually know about `wh` and `per`.  In your toy example there are quicker ways as each row of `whr` is the same, but I assume you are looking for something more general.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. You can imagine the elements of whr to  be different at each row. So you can have wi1,wi2,wi3, which are not in order. I need order the matrix in such a way that for each j, it will be written in the form wj1,wj2,wj3 (instead of wj2,wj1,wj3 let's say)